# How to iterate through a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

For iteration in a linked list, such that `LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();` can I iterate through the strings in the linked list using `for (String t: list)`?

Comment: Might be helpful to mention the language. Java? Also, did you even try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, as long as the list is declared to contain strings - notice the generic type parameter:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
// fill list

for (String s : list) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did add the string object in my question... but for some reason it doesn't show up here.

Comment: @user1628527 no problem, I edited the question to fix the formatting issues. Did this solve the problem? if so please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer ;)